# Getting child in array no key error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the below error. However, I believe I have correctly put a unique key on the li element. Do I need to do it somewhere else?

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `ListBooks`. 
        in Book (at ListBooks.js:26)
        in ListBooks (at App.js:60)
```

Code from the Book.js file

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.book.id);
  return (
    <li key={this.props.book.id}>
      <div className="book">
        <div className="book-top">
          <div
            className="book-cover"
            style={{
              width: 128,
              height: 193,
              backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.book.imageLinks.thumbnail})`,
            }}
          />
          <div className="book-shelf-changer">
            <select
              value={this.getShelfFromBook(this.props.book)}
              onChange={event =>
                this.props.updateSelect(this.props.book, event.target.value)
              }
            >
              <option value="disabled" disabled>
                Move to...
              </option>
              <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
              <option value="currentlyReading">Currently Reading</option>

              <option value="read">Read</option>
              <option value="none">None</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="book-title">{this.props.book.title}</div>
        <div className="book-authors">{this.props.book.authors}</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Code from the parent component

```
{
  wantRead.map(book => (
    <Book
      updateSelect={this.props.updateSelect}
      book={book}
      books={this.props.books}
    />
  ));
}
```

Github reference [here](https://github.com/robineyre29/reactnd-project-myreads-starter)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `key` prop on the `<Book>` list, not inside the `<Book>` component:

```
{
  wantRead.map(book => (
    <Book
      key={book.id}
      updateSelect={this.props.updateSelect}
      book={book}
      books={this.props.books}
    />
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#extracting-components-with-keys)

> Keys only make sense in the context of the surrounding array.

So the key should be on `<Book />` within the `map`

Answer (score 0):

you need a uniqe key for each child

so you can use node-uuid

```

```
npm install uuid
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');
//uuidv1(); ⇨ 'f64f2940-fae4-11e7-8c5f-ef356f279131'


{
  wantRead.map(book => (
    <Book
      key={uuidv1()}
      updateSelect={this.props.updateSelect}
      book={book}
      books={this.props.books}
    />
  ));
}
```

```

Comment: OP already has `book.id`, why introduce another unique id? And from an other library nonetheless?